# Unable to take a sum of a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)

sum' :: (Integral a) => [a] -> a
sum' [] = 0
sum' [a] = foldr (+) 0 ([a])

main = do putStrLn "Enter a number:"
          num <- readLn
          sum' (take num fibs)
```

That's my code to take the sum of a recursively produced list.

I could have done the `foldr` operation at `take num fibs`, but I wanted more control over the list and wanted a way in which I could take the sum of particular elements of a list rather than the whole list.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Your `sum'` function is incorrect:

```
sum' [a] = foldr (+) 0 ([a])
```

This will only accept, and sum, a list of 1 element. :-)

Change it to:

```
sum' a = foldr (+) 0 a
```

And it will work.

You can also delete the redundant `sum' [] = 0` line, and extend the type to `sum' :: (Num a) => [a] -> a`.

Comment: That doesn't really solve my purpose. As in, I get the total sum always. And not the sum of two elements of a particular position. Hence the confusion.

Comment: @Hick I see.  Could you be more specific?  What do you mean by "two elements of a particular position"?  For the fibonacci sequence, the sum of two *consecutive* elements is represented by the next, so `fibs!!5` will be the sum of elements 3 and 4.

Comment: Exactly. hence when I do a (take num fibs) !! num here, it crops up an error as the initial list of numbers is always greater than the list that is being computed, recursively.

Comment: What did you want to come out of `(take num fibs) !! num`?

Comment: so say I assign num as 200, the (take num fibs) !! num should give me the sum of 199 and 198th element. Else I've completely understood it wrong.

Comment: `fibs` is an infinite list. `take num fibs` results in a finite list of `num` elements, the last valid index being `num-1`. `x!!y` returns the element at index `y` from list `x`.  So, if you want to get the sum of two consecutive numbers starting at index `i`, just `fibs!!(i+2)` will do.  If you want the roundabout route, you can increase your temporary finite list by 1 element: `(take (num + 1) fibs) !! num`.

Comment: `sum' (take num fibs)` has type `Integral a => a` but every statement in a `do` block must have type `IO a`. Try `putStrLn $ show $ sum' (take num fibs)` or `let var = sum' (take num fibs)`

Comment: Also notice that `sum' (take num fibs)` will give the sum of the `num` first numbers of `fibs`, which is *not* the next number in the sequence.